# В чём сохранить несколько переменных?

Tags: java, парсер

Пишу один парсер на java. 
Нужно вот такого рода переменные сохранить в листе или в чём-то другом.

```
index, id, (type, x, y, z)

       id1, (type1, x1, y1, z1)

       id2, (type2, x2, y2, z2)
```

index главная переменная, то есть к ней будут идти все обращения с параметрами 
(index 1, id1 - id*)

Answer (score 3):

`(type, x, y, z)` заверните в отдельный класс (например `Params`)и складывайте его в `Map<String, Params>` (смотря что у вас там в качестве `id`)

Answer (score 0):

Удобно в массиве, но лучше как посоветовал Nofare.